# Searching for perfect power number

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers

The program works in all cases except ((i^2) *2). For example, 18(because of (3^2)*2 it returns[3,3]) or 50 (because of (5^2)*2 it returns[5,3]), but 27 and 125 for this cases also work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class  test  {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //enter the number(n) from keyboard
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String str=null;
        double numb=(double)n;
        int count=0;
        *
        List<Integer> answer=new ArrayList<>();

           //Divide the number(numb) until it equals the result or not
            for ( int i =2;i<50;i++){
                while(numb % i==0){
                    numb=numb/i;
                    count++;
                     if (numb ==i){
                        answer.add((int)numb);
                        answer.add(count+1);
                            break;
                     }
                }
            }
        if(answer.size()==0){
            System.out.println(str);
        }else{
            int []array = answer.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now what is the question here? What are you expecting your little program to do?

Comment: @Blindleistung how to solve also cases that I described at the top of the program?

Comment: I'm confused. 18 is not a [perfect power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power) number. --- (3^3)*2 is 54, not 18. 2*3*3 is 18, which makes it not a power number, because it has two different factors. --- (5^5)*2 is 6250, not 50, 2*5*5 is 50, and again is not a power number. --- Seems the entire premise of your question is flawed.

Comment: @ Andreas Probably, my question was asked incorrectly. I meant that 18 and 50 are not perfect power numbers but the program interprets them. Others cases are ok

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to divide your input number by any numbers from 2..50 . Non-prime numbers could be skipped, but they don't hurt. (e.g. 10 finds no division after already processing 2 and 5).

For every value of `i`, you divide it out as long as this works, and if the remaining number equals `i` AFTER dividing it out, it is added to the list called `answer`. This means that at the end, answer will only contain the highest prime factor below 50, if this prime factor appears in the value at least twice. Only then can the result of the division equal `i`. If you are just looking for the highest prime, check if the result just dropped to 1.

You did not post what you want to achieve. But this was probably not intended.